# Determine the integers $m$ such that $1+2+3+....m=$ a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I went like this

> $ \frac{m(m+1)}{2} = k^2 
> ; m^2+m = 2k^2$

From here I noticed that m is even that is $m =2q$
 Substituting it will give

> $ 2q^2+q = k^2$

From here I got no where..

Then I thought perfect square can be expressed as sum of consecutive odd number.I tried that way it too ended similarly. Any ideas for progress??

Comment: The observation about $\ m\ $ being even is not obvious.

Comment: It's even FALSE: $\ m=k=1\ $ gives a counter-example.

Comment: Another quick solution is $\ m=8\ $ with $\ k=6.$

Comment: Oh thanks i forget m could be 1 mod 2

Comment: Did you do it by trial and error??

Comment: Do you mean $\ (m\ k)\ :=\ (8\ 6)?\ $ -- these are such small numbers that it's hard to call it by "trial & error" (what error? :) ). Most of us know by heart about the special pair $\ (8\ 9)\ =\ (2^3\,\ 3^2)$.

Comment: What does the special pair has to do with this problem??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98686/discussion-between-mathematical-curiosity-and-wlod-aa).

Comment: C'mon, $\ 2^3\ = 2\cdot a^2\ $ and $\ 3^2=9=2^3+1.$

Comment: There was no discussion. I've provided 2 solutions, and you have asked some simple ad hoc questions. Anyway, I am not into any chat, it's not my cup of tea.

Comment: Would you like to accept an answer, Mathematical?

Answer (score 1):

So, $4q^2+4q+1=2k^2+1$, that is $r^2-2k^2=1$ where $r=2q+1$. This is a
case of [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Comment: Can any one tell me how to write in lines?? When I write it automatically merges all lines

Comment: Try pressing Enter to leave a line gap between places you want to have separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be said as there is a number which is the  $m$th triangular number and also $k$th square number. Actually, there is a number called [square triangular number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number). There is a sequence of finding the $m$ and $k$.

Answer (score 1):

> (Since only half of the solutions were addressed so far, or none sufficiently explicitly, let me provide all of them).

We have to solve

$$ m\cdot(m+1)\ =\ 2\cdot k^2 $$

i.e. $\ 2\cdot k^2\ =\ L\cdot M\ $ where
$\ \{L\ M\}=\{m\,\ m+1\}\ $ is a product of two consecutive natural numbers. Then one of them, say $\ M,\ $ has to be odd,
and consequently, the other one, $\ L,\ $ has to be even; it
follows that $\ L=2\cdot\lambda^2\ $ and $\ M=\mu^2\ $ for certain natural numbers $\ \lambda\ \mu.\ $ In effect, we obtain equation

$$ |L-M| = 1 $$
i.e.
$$ |2\cdot\lambda^2\ -\ \mu^2|\ =\ 1 $$

It's well known (and not too hard to prove) that all solutions
form the following sequence:

$$ \lambda_0:=\mu_0:=1 $$
and
$$ \forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\quad
 (\,\lambda_n:=\lambda_{n-1}+\mu_{n-1}\,\ \mbox{and}
    \ \ \mu_n:=\lambda_n+\lambda_{n-1}\,) $$
Thus, finally:

$$ m_s :=\ \mu_s^2\qquad \forall\ s\ \mbox{odd} $$
and
$$ m_t :=\ 2\cdot\lambda_t^2\qquad \forall\ t\ \mbox{even} $$

and, of course,

$$ \forall_{r\in\mathbb N}\quad k_r\ =\ \lambda_r\cdot\mu_r $$

provides all solutions $\ (m\ k)\ :=\ (m_r\ k_r),\ $
where $\ r\in\mathbb N$.